# Google Sheet API append to a specific sheet

Tags: google-api, google-sheets-api

according to the [API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append) it seems that I can't specify the sheet where to append the data. It appends everything in the first sheet. Is it really like this?

Beacuse I can create a file with multiple sheets, but then I can't write on the second sheet?

Comment: Is there any to append data under specific headers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you simply want to write on a sheet, follow the [Basic Writing Sheets guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/writing). You can write on a sheet by using a PUT method:

```
PUT https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/spreadsheetId/values/Sheet1!A1:D5?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED
```

and specify the name of sheet and cell range in like:

```
{
  "range": "Sheet1!A1:D5",
  "majorDimension": "ROWS",
  "values": [
    ["Item", "Cost", "Stocked", "Ship Date"],
    ["Wheel", "$20.50", "4", "3/1/2016"],
    ["Door", "$15", "2", "3/15/2016"],
    ["Engine", "$100", "1", "30/20/2016"],
    ["Totals", "=SUM(B2:B4)", "=SUM(C2:C4)", "=MAX(D2:D4)"]
  ],
}
```

With regard to your `spreadsheets.values.append` question, I'm sure you've already read what the docs had to say:

> Appends values to a spreadsheet. The input range is used to search
>   for existing data and find a "table" within that range. Values will be
>   appended to the next row of the table, starting with the first column
>   of the table.

This is only for adding at the last row of the table.

Answer (score 5):

The solution is to specify the sheet title in the {range} parameter found on the *awful-as-always* [Google Sheets API docs](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update).

Below are the request deets on a updating the value on sheet2...

URL:

```
PUT https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{someSpreadsheetId}/values/sheet2!A1:D3?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED
```

BODY:

```
{
  "values": [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
  ]
}
```

Note that the title of the second sheet, "sheet2" prepends what I would have considered the range: "A1:D3" with an exclamation delimiter.
    sheet2!A1:D3