# Java Google Sheet API. Append data to specific sheets

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want to append data to a 3 different sheets (using Java and Google Sheet API).

For example, "I like turtles" to the first sheet which sheetId is 1, "123" to the second sheet which sheetId is 2 and any range to the second sheet which sheetId is 3. How to append that data? And more important, how to get sheetId from sheets and set active sheet ? Or any other way to do this. Any suggestions or maybe examples?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You may refer with this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41067256/google-sheet-api-append-to-a-specific-sheet) on how to append data to a specific sheets.

> If you simply want to write on a sheet, follow the [Basic Writing Sheets guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/writing). You can write on a sheet by using a PUT method:
>
> ```
> PUT https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/spreadsheetId/values/Sheet1!A1:D5?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED
> ```
>
> and specify the name of sheet and cell range in like:
>
> ```
> {
>   "range": "Sheet1!A1:D5",
>   "majorDimension": "ROWS",
>   "values": [
>     ["Item", "Cost", "Stocked", "Ship Date"],
>     ["Wheel", "$20.50", "4", "3/1/2016"],
>     ["Door", "$15", "2", "3/15/2016"],
>     ["Engine", "$100", "1", "30/20/2016"],
>     ["Totals", "=SUM(B2:B4)", "=SUM(C2:C4)", "=MAX(D2:D4)"]
>   ],
> }
> ```
>
> With regard to your `spreadsheets.values.append` question, I'm sure you've already read what the docs had to say:
>
> > Appends values to a spreadsheet. The input range is used to search for existing data and find a "table" within that range. Values will be appended to the next row of the table, starting with the first column of the table.
>
> This is only for adding at the last row of the table.

Also from this [page](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/ay5I6uSfaWY):

> Try out the below script and see if that works for you:
>
> ```
>  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
>  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
>
>  // This represents ALL the data
>  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
>  var values = range.getValues();
>
>  // This logs the spreadsheet in CSV format with a trailing comma
>  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
>    var row = "";
>    for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
>      if (values[i][j]) {  
>        row = row + values[i][j];
>      }  
>      row = row + ",";    
>    }    
>    Logger.log(row);    
>  }
> ```
>
> This apps script will help you get data from one spreadsheet to another. Refer to the article [`getDataRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange) for more information on this.

Hope this helps!